# Def. of Homology Cell

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I would like an explanation for the following definition.

"A metric space is an $\ homology \ cell $ if it is nonempty and homologically trivial (acyclic) in all dimensions."

1. What does "homologically trivial (acyclic)" mean?
2. What are intuitive examples of homology cells?

Comment: Are you aware of what the homology of a topological space is? If not, I would suggest first picking up a basic text on algebraic topology. A space $X$ is acyclic if $\tilde{H}_n(X)=0$ for all $n\geq 0$ where $\tilde{H}_n(X)$ is the $n$-th reduced homology group of the space $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I'm guessing you don't know what homology is, so answering this will be challenging. The first homology $H_1(X)$ is easy to define. It is the abelianization of the fundamental group. So in particular the fundamental group of a homology cell must be perfect (equal to its own commutator subgroup.) The definitions of $H_2$ and higher homology groups require a fair bit of machinery.

A simple example of a homology cell is any contractible space. (This is actually a homotopy cell, which is a stronger condition.) A less trivial example arises by taking the Poincare homology sphere (Google it!) and removing the interior of a small ball. This space has a nonzero fundamental group so it cannot be a homotopy ball, but all of its (reduced) homology groups vanish.